# How to return True when finding a directory from the list?

Tags: python, list, operating-system

How to return True if a directory is found from a list?

Sorry for the stupid question, I just can’t figure out how to do this for about 2 hours

```
import os

OrganizationsPaths = (
    'C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\foobar.txt',
    'C:\\Users\\Peter Wilson\\Desktop\\Microsoft Word 2010.lnk',
    'C:\\Users\\Lisa\\Desktop',
    'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\decoy.cpp',
    'C:\\Users\\Jason\\Desktop')

def Organization():
 for Organization in OrganizationsPaths:
  if os.path.exists(Organization):
   return True
  return False
```

It is required to make the output True (if a directory is found) or False (if no directories are found from the list)

Comment: use list comprehension, ``[org for org in OrganizationsPaths if os.path.exists(org)]``

Comment: This works, but how can I put this in a function and return True or False?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: It is required to make the output True (if a directory is found) or False (if no directories are found from the list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

```
def organization():
    return any([os.path.exists(org) for org in OrganizationsPaths])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your check in a function, you could pass the Path as a Parameter:

```
def Organization(OrganizationsPaths): 
    for i in OrganizationsPaths:
        if os.path.exists(i):
            return True
        return False

print(Organization(OrganizationsPaths))
```

Comment: Consider renaming ``Organization`` variable name in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is one problem: it only checks the first and only directory from the list. How can i fix this?

Comment: In this case you could return a list of existing paths instead. Do you want to try it by yourself?